# Do GPO's cascade throughout child resources?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

For example, imagine I have a GPO rule that states that nobody can change their wallpaper.

In a child user group, would a GPO stating **it can** change take higher priority?

Sort of like CSS, more specific CSS rules take effect. Is this the case with GPO's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general terms, yes. There are exceptions though.

The general rule of GPO processing is LSDOU: Local policy, Site level policy, Domain level policy, and Organization Unit policy.

Four settings can affect the application of Group Policy: Enforcement, Inheritance Blocking, Loopback processing, and GPO filtering. Here's a link to Microsoft's Group Policy home page for further study:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732

Comment: Thank you. :) So an OU policy takes the *least* precedence? That seems odd...

Comment: No. An OU level policy takes precedence, with exceptions. Local policy is applied first, then Site level policy, then Domain level policy, and finally OU level policy.

Comment: Processing is the exact opposite of precedence, the last GPO setting applied is what is set

Comment: @Jim B: Right, The GPO with the lowest link order is processed last, and therefore has the highest precedence.